# How to stay on .html after pressing upload button which opens php script?

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I have this code in my `.html` file:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">Select file to upload:        
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit">
</form>
```

What parts of the code should I modify?

Comment: for such simple task yo can combine .html & .php into one PHP file.

Comment: Your title says you need to stay on the same HTML, but your question content says that you want to *go back* to the same HTML. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following after your append code in `upload.php`:

```
header('Location: /path/to/original.html');
```

It does not *stay* on the original `.html` file per se, but it does go back to the form so you can do more uploads.

Comment: I added this code and it stays on the original .html file :) That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: you may accept it as the correct answer then (gray checkmark next to the up/down vote arrows on the left of my answer), thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ajax to upload the files to the server :

The HTML code :

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">Select file to upload:        
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submitForm" name="submitForm">
</form>
```

The jQuery code could be something like this :

```
$('#submitForm').on('click', function() {
   var file_data = $('#fileToUpload').prop('files')[0];   
   var form_data = new FormData();                  
   form_data.append('file', file_data);                           
   $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
            dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                         
            type: 'post',
            success: function(php_script_response){
                alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
            }
     });
});
```

I would love to know if this code worked out well for you

Comment: I don't agree, you don't *need* to use ajax for this... you *can* use ajax, but it isn't a *must* in order this to work, check out my answer...

Comment: Webno ... read well the question ... "How to stay on the .html" 
Ajax upload permits you to stay on the page ... Your solution although is correct ... doesnt keeps you on the page
Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't correct, I just said it's not necessary to achieve the goal of not having to go back... I agree with you, if they *effectively* wanted to stay on the same page for some reason, ajax would indeed be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax as **arizona31** already mentioned.

Other you also could make the upload.php a class like:

```
<?php
    class upload {
        function __construct($file){
            $this->file = $file;
        }

        function upload_file(){
            // Create the upload code using the $this->file variable.
        }
    }
?>
```

and use some HTML/PHP to create a object of this class:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:        
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $uplaod = new upload($_POST['fileToUpload']);
        $upload->upload_file();
    }
?>
```

There's several ways  to do this.